# Deploy Nuxt on shared hosting

Tags: vue.js, web-deployment, nuxt.js

I want to know if it is possible to deploy Nuxt app on a shared hosting.
After running `npm run build --spa` it generated below file structure in the `dist` directory, but don't know how to go from here.

[nuxt dist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7X2q.png)

Comment: I think it is as simple as copying content of dist folder to your host. Then try yourdomain.com/server 

Answer (score 5):

Here are some checklists to deploy your spa app on hosting.

1. Did you configured your nuxt app as spa? You have to set your nuxt application `spa` mode in `nuxt.config.js`.

   - Reference: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode/
2. Can you configure rewrite rule on your hosting? If you build your application via `build --spa` you need to configure rewrite rule that rewrite all request into `index.html`. This is sample configuration on Firebase Hosting.

   ```
   {
     "hosting": {
       "public": "dist",
       "ignore": [
          "firebase.json",
         "**/.*",
         "**/node_modules/**"
       ],
       "rewrites": [
         {
           "source": "**",
           "destination": "/index.html"
         }
       ]
     }
   }
   ```
3. If you can't configure rewrite rule on your hosting, then you can build your application via `generate`.

   - Reference: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/

All checklist passed, then just upload your `dist` directory on your hosting! That's all!

Answer (score 0):

Upload whats inside the build which is dist/ folder to public folder or from where the shared hosting domain points to after generating the pages.

If you're just gonna use it statically I suggest you better use some advanced static pages hosting with many benefits such as free ssl, CDN support, and push to deploy. e.g netlify.com, zeit.co/now .

This would only take you few minutes of learning and huge benefits in a lifetime.